# Finding elements in treemap

Tags: java, object

I want to find out whether a number passed through a method is part of a randomly generated object (created from a tree map). I've been looking online to find an attribute to the class that can help me find it but have come up short, I've tried HashCodes, Equals(), and this the like... At the moment I have it set up like this and what I'm asking, I guess, is whether I'm using what I read right or wrong?

```
Here's the code:


public class a {
private final TreeMap<Integer,TreeMap<Integer,Double>> rectangle;
private final int height;
private final int width;

public a(int h, int w) {
    this.rectangle = new TreeMap<>();
    this.height = h;
    this.width =  w;
} 

 public double get(int i, int j) {
if ( i > j ) {
   largest = i;  // defined earlier
}
for(int a = 0; a < largest; a++) {
    if (this.height.equals(a) == i && this.width.equals(a) == j){
int[] position = new int[1];
position[0] = i;
position[1] = j;``
    }
    else {
        return 0.0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "randomly generated object (created from a tree map)"

Comment: Sorry for my bad working... It's an object in the instance of a treemap? I'm not sure how to word it...

Comment: Can we have a look at what instance1 and instance2 is then? I suspect they are treemaps, in which case they will never be equal to an integer, are you creating a treemap with random integer content? Then the test needs to look a bit different.

Comment: I don't think you've copied the code correctly or there are more obvious errors: `this.instance1.equals(a) == i` should not be valid code and neither is `return i j;`. Can you please make sure this code is compilable first and also where are your TreeMaps? What are instance1 and instance2? TreeMaps?

Comment: You still haven't really said what it is you want to do exactly. If you want to know if a TreeMap contains a particular number you can say `rectangle.containsKey(someNumber)`. It just isn't possible to answer your question without knowing exactly what you want to do. What does `rectangle` actually have in it? What is `get` actually supposed return? Right now `get` doesn't do anything with `rectangle`. Otherwise I recommend looking at this page: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_collections.htm which outlines the major Collections classes and how to use them.